# apollo client offsetLimitPagination not working

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have a `hook`..

```js
export function useLazyProposalList() {
  const [getQueueData, { loading, data, error, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(PROPOSAL_LIST, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });

  const proposalList = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return null;
    }
    return transformProposals(data);
  }, [data]);

  return {
    getQueueData,
    fetchMore,
    loading,
    data: proposalList,
    error,
  };
}
```

In the component

```js
const {
    getQueueData,
    data: queueData,
    fetchMore: fetchMoreProposals,
    // loadMore: loadMore,
  } = useLazyProposalList();
```

If user clicks on `fetch more` button, I call: `fetchMoreProposals` .

```js
await fetchMoreProposals({
        variables: {
          offset: visibleProposalList.length,
        },
      });
```

but this doesn't update my data. I read that we should use `offsetLimitPagination`, but  my data from query is not array itself. It's like this: `queue { id: '1', items:[] }` and because of this, `offsetLimitPagination` doesn't work. So I tried merge

```js
cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          queue: {
            keyArgs: false,
            merge(existing, incoming) {
              console.log(existing, incoming);
              if (!incoming) return existing;
              if (!existing) return incoming;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

but in the console, it just prints refs instead of real data.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: bad `variables` - not an object, check network request

Comment: I updated the question and included the correct `variables` now.. The problem now is that in the merge function, I still get `refs`.

Comment: use/play with `read` function (even as simple as `return existing`) ... nested? ... take an inspiration from relay style (data nested in edges/nodes): https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/utilities/policies/pagination.ts#L87 .... refs? I see objects with data inside

Comment: @xadm here is what I mean exactly. - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/discussions/8264

Comment: I know what you mean ... follow working [and complete] examples, not your expectations/wishes, ... it works ... if properly defined ... you could use `updateQuery`, it works, too (with outdated warning), I tested both methods on data 'nested' in `edges`

Comment: @xadm you don't understand. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/cefb3c32621de6973191c7abb6edd365d53cbf41/src/utilities/policies/pagination.ts#L103 I can't do something like this because in my example, it's already a ref. please read my question https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/discussions/8264

Comment: proofs? bad config? prepare working, editable [example] on codesandbox